# How to create a cumulative list of values, by group, in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, cumsum

I'm trying to add a new column to the DataFrame, that consists of a cumulative list (by group) of another column.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'group1': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
```

Expected output:

```
   group1  value cumsum_column
0       1      1           [1]
1       1      2        [1, 2]
2       2      3           [3]
3       2      4        [3, 4]
4       2      5     [3, 4, 5]
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

One way I've tried that doesn't work:

```
df['value_list'] = [[i] for i in df['value']]
df['cumsum_column'] = df.groupby('group1')['value_list'].cumsum()
```

This throws the error:

```
TypeError: cumsum is not supported for object dtype
```

EDIT:
To be clearer, I'm looking to find out *why* this is not working + looking for the *fastest* way for this to happen — as I'm looking to use it on big dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom function in [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
def accumulate(s):
    out = [[]]
    for x in s:
        out.append(out[-1]+[x])
    return out[1:]

df['cumsum_column'] = df.groupby('group1')['value'].transform(accumulate)
```

Output:

```
   group1  value cumsum_column
0       1      1           [1]
1       1      2        [1, 2]
2       2      3           [3]
3       2      4        [3, 4]
4       2      5     [3, 4, 5]
```

##### Why your solution failed?

because [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) is restricted to numeric data (Thus the "*TypeError: cumsum is not supported for object dtype*" error).

You would have needed to use a lambda in `transform` (`df.groupby('group1')['value_list'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum())`.

##### timings:

Tested on 100k rows with 100 groups.

```
%%timeit
df['cumsum_column'] = df.groupby('group1')['value'].transform(accumulate)
# 199 ms ± 12.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
df['value_list'] = [[i] for i in df['value']]
df['cumsum_column'] = df.groupby('group1')['value_list'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum())
# 207 ms ± 7.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
f = lambda x: [list(x)[:i] for i, y in enumerate(x, 1)]
df['cumsum_column'] = df.groupby('group1')['value'].transform(f)
# 6.65 s ± 483 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

### fix of the logic of the other solution to run faster
%%timeit
g = df.groupby('group1')['value']
d = g.agg(list)
df['cumsum_column'] = [d[k][:i] for k, grp in g for i, x in enumerate(grp, start=1)]
# 207 ms ± 10.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

[image]

Comment: For `df['cumsum_column'] = df.groupby('group1')['value_list'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum())` is necessary add `df['value_list'] = [[i] for i in df['value']]`, thank you.

Comment: Ah okay — so the cumsum() function works differently for Series vs DataFrames. Do you know why that is the case? Thanks for also adding the timings, accepted your answer as it's the most complete.

Comment: Here you were using [`groupby.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) which is yet another function ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function:

```
f = lambda x: [list(x)[:i] for i, y in enumerate(x, 1)]
df['cumsum_column'] = df.groupby('group1')['value'].transform(f)  
print (df)
   group1  value cumsum_column
0       1      1           [1]
1       1      2        [1, 2]
2       2      3           [3]
3       2      4        [3, 4]
4       2      5     [3, 4, 5]
```

Thank you @mozway for improved solution:

```
g = df.groupby('group1')['value']
d = g.agg(list)
df['cumsum_column'] = [d[k][:i] for k, grp in g for i, x in enumerate(grp, 1)]
```

> I'm looking to find out why this is not working

In my opinion pandas devs want performant solution for [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) working only with numeric data.

---

Your solution working with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['value_list'] = [[i] for i in df['value']]
df['cumsum_column'] = df.groupby('group1')['value_list'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum())
print (df)
   group1  value value_list cumsum_column
0       1      1        [1]           [1]
1       1      2        [2]        [1, 2]
2       2      3        [3]           [3]
3       2      4        [4]        [3, 4]
4       2      5        [5]     [3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

i like

```py
def fun(ser):
    return [ser.head(i+1).to_list() for i in range(len(ser))]

df['cumsum_column'] = df.groupby('group1').value.transform(fun)
```

or even (fully in pandas)

```py
def fun2(ser):
    return ( 
        pd
        .Series(range(len(ser)))
        .add(1)
        .map(lambda i : ser.head(i).to_list())
        .set_axis(ser.index)
    )

df['cumsum_column'] = df.groupby('group1').value.transform(fun2)
```